# To remove widow word at the end of the each paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hi guys I'm new to vba macro I'll get into the topic I'm working on the word document which converted from pdf so it sometimes has widow word at the end of the some paragraph. I need to do the work of remove the space before it and add the previous word with non breaking space. I tried to use macro to solve this issue after some work i got this but still this only removes the space before the last word and add non breaking space and loop into the same paragraph its not moving to next paragraph and also it not finding the widow word. i don't know what to do please help.

```
Private Sub CombineLastWord()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim words() As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        If Len(para.Range.Text) > 2 Then 
            words = Split(para.Range.Text, " ")
            If UBound(words) > 0 Then 
                i = UBound(words)
                words(i - 1) = words(i - 1) & ChrW(160) & words(i) 
                words(i) = "" ' Clear the last word
                para.Range.Text = Join(words, " ")
            End If
        End If
    Next para
End Sub
```

This doesn't find if the paragraph having widow word or not simple combine the last word with previous word.
I need it only to find widow word and clear the space and introduce NBS and it has to be done on the entire document.

Answer (score 0):

When you Open a PDF in Word there should be no "Widow Word", and thus it depends also what you mean by that description. Hence we ask for a sample file that reproduces your problem.

Here we can see with a sample file there are no unexpected behaviours, as Word has added the PDF lines into grouped paragraphs (since PDF generally does not have those, they need to be built from parts of line text during import.) I also added the help text for widow controls.

[image]

First pass you use grammar checker to clear the faults. Then enblock make other styling changes. And then finally look for those "Widows", whatever they may be ?

[image]